# What is difference between express checkout and direct payment in paypal pro?

Tags: paypal

What is difference between **express checkout** and **direct payment** in **paypal pro**?

Comment: express checkout is when say you have a buy button on your site and i click it, i will be redirected to paypal where i will login and accept to pay you a certain amount. as for direct payment you have the credit card fields on your website and i enter my credit card details and click checkout and all the transactions occur on your website and i never see paypal. direct payment is direct payment on your site without seeing the actual process behind the scenes.